# Adding LineString from points using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, point, polyline-creation

I want to create a LineString using points/coordinates in QGIS 3.26 using Python/PyQGIS.

Here is my code :

```py
points = []

x = QgsPointXY(783648,1397243)
points.append(x)

y = QgsPointXY(788883,1396853)
points.append(y)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

fields = layer.dataProvider().fields()

feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points))
feature.setFields(fields)
feature.setAttribute(0,12)

layer.addFeature(feature)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

I am facing no error but I can't see any LineString in QGIS from the given points.

Comment: Try `layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])`. And remove the last line. If your layer is in the layers panel it is already added to the project. Replace it with `layer.triggerRepaint()`.

Comment: Thank you this works

Comment: Is this a LineString?

Comment: The error you may get is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dataProvider'`

Comment: Yes its a linestring

Comment: I have converted my comment to an answer so please don't forget about: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental reason why your code is not working is that you are trying to add a feature to your layer without making it editable. If you want to immediately commit the changes to the layer's underlying data store, you should work with `layer.dataProvider()` instead. Also, you should remove the last line from your code snippet, since the active layer is already added to the project, and replace it with a few lines to reflect the changes to the layer.

```py
points = []
x = QgsPointXY(783648,1397243)
points.append(x)
y = QgsPointXY(788883,1396853)
points.append(y)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

if layer.dataProvider().capabilities() & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points))
    feature.setAttributes([0, 12])
    layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
    layer.updateExtents()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    # Optional...
    iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

On the other hand, if you want the opportunity to undo/ redo then save the edits via the GUI, you can just call `layer.startEditing()` before adding the feature to the layer:

```py
points = []
x = QgsPointXY(783648,1397243)
points.append(x)
y = QgsPointXY(788883,1396853)
points.append(y)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

if layer.type() == QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer:
    feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(points))
    feature.setAttributes([0, 12])

    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()
        
    layer.addFeature(feature)
    layer.updateExtents()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    # Optional...
    iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```

I strongly recommend reading the [PyQGIS Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html) section on [Modifying Vector Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers).

Comment: thank you, this worked for me.